# SQL Join with two ON clauses (Nested Join?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, syntax

I am debugging a report that has been created by someone else and it has the join criteria below. (I have laid out to my preference and anonymised the table names)

```
SELECT  --columns
FROM    Table1
        JOIN Table2
        JOIN Table3
            ON Table2.pred = Table3.pred
        JOIN Table4
            ON Table2.pred = Table4.pred
        JOIN Table5
            ON Table2.pred = Table5.pred AND Table2.pred = Table5.pred AND Table3.pred = Table5.pred
        JOIN Table6
            ON Table3.pred = Table6.pred
            ON Table1.pred = Table5.pred AND Table1.pred = Table5.pred
        LEFT JOIN Table7
            ON Table5.pred = Table7.pred AND Table5.pred = Table7.pred
        LEFT JOIN Table7 AS Table7_1
            ON Table5.pred = Table7_1.pred AND Table5.pred = Table7_1.pred
WHERE   --conditions
```

What I find confusing is that there is no join that associates Table1 with Table 2 and there are two ON clauses after the join to table 6. Usually multiple tables are joined:

```
FROM  Table
      JOIN Table2
          ON --criteria
      JOIN Table3
          ON --criteria
      JOIN Table4
          ON --criteria
      --etc
```

The query works but as someone trying to work out what it is doing I am struggling as I have never seen the join syntax before.

is anyone able to explain the syntax to me?

Comment: Did you leave out any parenthesis in your editing of the original query?

Comment: Valid syntax, an explanation was already given while I was writing it. YOu might wanna tell that person to rethink their code ethics. This is TERRIBLE code and can be redone in 2 minutes to be so much more readable.

Comment: Agreed, I will be restructuring it but first I needed to understand what was joining to what!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is valid syntax.  Here is a simpler example:

```
from t1 join
     t2 join
     t3
     on t2.? = t3.?
     on t1.? = t2.?
```

If written with parentheses, it makes more sense:

```
from t1 join
     (t2 join
      t3
      on t2.? = t3.?
     ) on t1.? = t2.?
```

Although allowed, I strongly discourage you from using this syntax.  Rewrite the query so the `join`s and `on`s are interleaved.

Comment: Thanks, adding the parentheses has made it understandable enough to refactor into "sensible" syntax

Comment: @SEarle1986 building queries incrementally can help generate this type of syntax more clearly and easily